# i got problem in reinstalling apache2 in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: apache2

I tried to reinstall apache2. But i cant reinstall it. I got this error.

[image: getting error]

Comment: Please paste the text as code rather than sharing screenshot

Comment: It seems there is a mistake in your apache config file which is coming from your previous installation. How did you uninstall apache before? Did you use purge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source your envvars file. This will set your apache2 environment vars for the current session and allow you to use the apache2 binary without modifying your config.

```
cd
source /etc/apache2/envvars
```

Restart apache2:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Show server version:

```
/usr/sbin/apache2ctl -V
```